# How do I get to a quest item that fell off the map in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm doing a mission with a power core after I defeated Wilhelm, but then the power core fell off the map. How do I retrieve it? I keep dying try to get it, dying and falling.

I have tried turning on demi-god mode in the game files to make myself invincible, but I just died falling off again.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the game and killing him again?

Comment: exit to main menu and load your game again . . . just like when you trying to farming bosses.

Comment: To be clear, it's not supposed to fall off like that. You should be able to just pick it up. It probably fell off because of where he was when you killed him.